# WSL to Windows interface

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

How do I transfer files between Windows and a Ubuntu WSL?
I tried to mount the disk image to access the files, but I'd regularly have to close the WSL instance to do so.
Can anyone suggest a more sustainable way to do so?

Comment: From Windows, the disk can be accessed from File Explorer by navigating to: `\\wsl$\\<Distro>\\<Mountpoint>`

Answer (score 2):

The way I transfer files between my Windows and WSL is with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php). You'll need to setup SSH server on WSL which could be installed by default, if not you can set it up like [here](https://devconnected.com/how-to-install-and-enable-ssh-server-on-ubuntu-20-04/). And WSL setup need additional change if it's not working with port 22, you can change it to some other port to make it work like [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1123552/how-to-ssh-into-wsl). After those steps, you can log in on `localhost` and port you chose with your username and password. Hope this makes it a bit more simple to transfer files!

Comment: Thanks! looked into it and implemented it
I rather liked having an xRDP with a light weight GUI and hosting it to remote desktop